# How to stop a Job after App's data was cleared?

Tags: java, android

I'm developing an Android App for my company (just people of my company are using it).

After login, user presses a *Check in* button, and this button starts a tracking Job. This job sends location every hour to our server, and it stops only when they leave the place (pressing a *Check out* button) or when departure time is reached.

The problem is, this job uses data that was downloaded when user logged in for the first time, and if they clear app data (*Settings -> App -> My app name -> Clear data*) , my Job won't stop, and next time it's triggered, the app will crash (because it didn't find data that was downloaded after logging in). The way I'm handling this is using a Shared Preferences variable "*tracking*", so that, if app data was cleared, tracking default value will be false and job will stop. Is there a better way to handle this? Can I know if my app's data was cleared?

I'm scheduling my job like this (Utilities.java):

```
public static void scheduleTrackingJob(Context context, PersistableBundle extraData){
    ComponentName serviceComponent = new ComponentName(context, TrackingJob.class);
    JobScheduler jobScheduler = (JobScheduler) context.getSystemService(
            Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE
    );

    assert jobScheduler != null;

    jobScheduler.cancel(TrackingJob.JOB_ID);
    jobScheduler.schedule(
            new JobInfo.Builder(TrackingJob.JOB_ID, serviceComponent)
                    .setPeriodic(TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(1))
                    .setExtras(extraData)
                    .setPersisted(false)
                    .build()
    );

    // Sets PREF_TRACKING (String "Tracking") = true on SharedPreferences
    setBoolean(context, PREF_TRACKING, true);
}

public static void stopTrackingJob(Context context, int jobID){
    JobScheduler jobScheduler = (JobScheduler) context.getSystemService(
            Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE
    );

    assert jobScheduler != null;

    jobScheduler.cancel(jobID);
    setBoolean(context, PREF_TRACKING, false);
}
```

Here I start my locationServices or, if tracking is false, I stop my job (TrackingJob.java)

```
// ... some code ...
@Override
public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters jobParameters) {
    // if Tracking is true, start location services
    if (Utilities.getBoolean(getApplicationContext(), Utilities.PREF_TRACKING)) {
        createLocationCallback(jobParameters);
        createLocationRequest();
        buildLocationSettingsRequest();
        startLocationServices(jobParameters);
        return true; // async call
    } else {
        Utilities.stopTrackingJob(getApplicationContext(), JOB_ID);
        return false;
    }
}
// ... more code ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use database for this type of requirements because when you clear data of app, it will clear all database or you can manage as per your needs.

Shared preference is a finer way but I believe database (Sqlite) or else will be a better approach. What you say about this?

Comment: Sure, I'm using realm, and thats the problem. I use data from realm after location is updated, but if app data was cleared, It won't find data from realm, that's why I'm using Shared Preferences, for adding a previous validation to my service. is like "_if data was cleared, don't use realm and cancel job_"

Comment: Deleting app data will also lead to delete the data from shared preference. I mean to say your app will behave as new app like it act as first time installation. So you need to reload the data or download your data again.

Comment: Yes, that's why, if data is not in Shared Preferences, it'll use "false" as default value and will stop my Job. 
And it's not possible to download my data again, because I need user's username, and I get that in my login acitvity

Comment: You can try Using the Internal Storage, store file to it and read it internally. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal